# mysql_query returns a row, but mysql_fetch_array does not do anything

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have a strange problem this time. I've got a masking database setup that takes in a url and gives it a string mask so that I can redirect users to another site (direct download) by giving them a link to my site's redirection engine.

I'm having a problem in the administrator side (where I put in the urls) where my mysql_fetch_array command just doesn't run. I know the query is returning at least one row because when I run the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE `in`='$lks[$i]' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";

$r = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($r) < 1)
echo "Less than 1";
else
echo "At least 1";
```

it returns "At least 1", but when it gets down to the mysql_fetch_array while statement, nothing happens. It's like it just ignores it completely.

CODE:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE `in`='$lks[$i]' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";

$r = mysql_query($query);

while($me = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    echo "Blah";
}
```

Nothing is echoed by this code. What's wrong?

By the way, I know that I am connected to the database and everything because I run other commands very similar to this before this one and they all execute without any problems.

Also this command is in a **for loop** (I don't know why this would be a problem because I have done this many times before and never had any problems).

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: do a var_dump($me);
also, echo out your $query variable to make sure it contains what you think it does. I'm not sure if array indexing inside "" will work properly.

Comment: where do I do the var_dump? After the while statement terminates, $me returns bool(false)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try echoing mysql_error(); I'm thinking it might be that you put your column and table names in quotes.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE in='$lks[$i]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$r = mysql_query($query);
if($r)
{
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($r);
if($rowCount == 1)
{
echo "1 row";
}
}
else
{
echo mysql_error(); 
}
```

if this doesn't work there must be something wrong with your array. :/

Comment: echo mysql_error(); returned nothing. Changing 'in' (hash quotes, not apostrophes) to in gave me an invalid resource error in the mysql_fetch_array() line.

Comment: Same thing. `if($r)` does run, but mysql_error returns nothing.

Comment: I also recommend NOT quoting column names.  AND on most servers they are case sensitive.

Comment: lol Sorry for all the edits guys :( I can't figure this stupid indention out.

Comment: Same thing, the resource is valid, it has returned one row, but it will not run mysql_fetch_array($r)

Comment: Man, what the flip is wrong with this thing... I'm as crazy as you. I can't see it.

Comment: OH FOUND IT!!! it was a problem with the concatenation. Thanks for your help. I'll give you the checkmark for this one ;)

Comment: lol I was just dumbfounded staring at my replica of yours (different column names), which was totally working. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE in='$lks[$i]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";`

should be:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE in='{$lks[$i]}' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";`

But like stated earlier, use PDO.

Comment: Adding that still did nothing. I'm still getting a valid result with 1 row in it, but the mysql_fetch_array command will not run.

Answer (score 0):

> You are checking for less then one row kindly echo mysql_num_rows($r)
>   and check how many rows were returned.
>
> or use die(mysql_error()) alongwith mysql_query to check for error.

Comment: echo mysql_num_rows($r); returns 1

Comment: Then it is impossible that it will not enter the while loop. Check for any syntax error in your code.

Comment: Why do you think I'm so confused. I even took it out of the while loop and hard-coded a url into the query so that I could see if that was the problem and the same thing happens, every time.

Comment: use print_r(mysql_fetch_array($r)) to check the result... whats the output. (Not in while loop)